# Code still waiting until loop ends despite using await Task.Run()

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a piece of code where I want to run a loop in the background using Task.Run() and update some UI elements within the loop using Invoke(). However, even after using await Task.Run(), the code still waits until the loop ends before proceeding to the next line of code.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (panel1.Controls.Contains(button))
    {
        button.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
        {
            // UI update logic here
        }));
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
});
```

I expected that by using await Task.Run(), the loop would run asynchronously in the background, allowing the code to continue executing. However, it seems that the code still waits for the loop to finish before moving forward.

Am I missing something here? How can I ensure that the code continues executing without waiting for the loop to end? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want to wait for it, don't `await` it?!

Comment: `however, it seems that the code still waits for the loop to finish before moving forward.` -- Yes, that's the purpose of the `await`.

Comment: I'm using `await Task.run`.

Comment: Yes, and you're awaiting the Task to complete.

Comment: `await ....` "stops" current method execution until the awaited task is finished and returns the control to the caller method.

Comment: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/understand-control-flow-async-await

Comment: I need to await the task in order to perform UI updates within the loop using button.Invoke().

Comment: Then perhaps you shouldn't `await`.  Be wary of the [X Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info), however.

Comment: So what should i do to fix this?

Comment: Read https://xyproblem.info first.  Evaluate whether or not you really do need a Task for this.  If you do actually need one, you might try instantiating a Task in a class variable, and just letting it run freely.  No need to await a result.  It will clean up after itself when the `while` loop exits.

Comment: ... or just use a Timer.

Comment: And don't use `Thread.Sleep` in async code. Make that `await Task.Delay` if at all appropriate in the first place. Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but a tight loop seems not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no serious problem. When you put `await` before an awaitable call (e.g. `Task.Run`) It waits for it to the end.

Definitely what you did prevents your `UI` thread from blocking. There was an old issue when we had no `async/await` on `WinForm, WPF, ...`.

So if you want to run this task on background you should do something like this:

```
 var BackgroundTask = Task.Run(() =>
 {
     while (panel1.Controls.Contains(button))
     {
         button.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
         {
             // UI update logic here
         }));
         Thread.Sleep(1);
     }
 });
```

Now you are able to stop this task whenever you wanted and It won't block your `UI` thread as before.

Comment: How do you stop the Task? -- This will throw an ObjectDisposedException at some point; at least remove `button` from `button.Invoke(...)`, so the dispatcher is the Form itself -- You should probably suggest to use an `IProgress<T>` delegate to perform the updates, synchronous invocations may (will) lead to *unexpected* (not really) results